# How to use ErrorHandlingDeserializer with spring cloud stream binder kafka to send the error record to the default DLQ topic?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka

I want to use ErrorHandlingDeserializer to handle **deserializing error** and use spring cloud stream binder kafka to send the error record to the default DLQ topic of Kafka binder `error.<destination>.<group>`.
The ErrorHandlingDeserializer can handle the error record and skip it as expected, but the record was not sent to the DLQ topic.
I know there is `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`. I have tried it but it didn't use the Kafka setting in Kafka binder for the producer when sending the DLQ record, and it sends to `<originalTopic>.DLT`. I don't want to have redundant Kafka setting. I have all Kafka connection and security setting in Kafka binder.
This is my application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-service
  cloud:
    ## ====================================================== Vault Setting Omitted ====================================================
    vault:
    ## ====================================================== Vault Setting Omitted ====================================================
    schemaRegistryClient:
      enabled: true
      endpoint: my-schema-registry.com
      basic:
        auth:
          # user: This property is resolved from Vault.
          # password: This property is resolved from Vault.
    stream:
      kafka:
        heartbeat:
          interval:
            ms: 1000
        binder:
          brokers: my-kafka-broker.com:9094
          ## =============================================== SerDes ====================================================
          consumer-properties:
            allow.auto.create.topics: false
            specific.avro.reader: true
            schema.registry.url: ${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}
            auto.register.schemas: false
            basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
            basic.auth.user.info: ${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.basic.auth.user}:${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.basic.auth.password}
          producer-properties:
            allow.auto.create.topics: false
            key.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            value.serializer: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroSerializer
            schema.reflection: true
            schema.registry.url: ${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.endpoint}
            auto.register.schemas: false
            basic.auth.credentials.source: USER_INFO
            basic.auth.user.info: ${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.basic.auth.user}:${spring.cloud.schemaRegistryClient.basic.auth.password}
          ## =========================================== Kafka Security Omitted ================================================
          configuration:
          ## =========================================== Kafka Security Omitted ================================================
        bindings:
          my-in-0:
            consumer:
              enableDlq: true
              autoCommitOnError: true
              configuration:
                key.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                value.deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.ErrorHandlingDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.key.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
                spring.deserializer.value.delegate.class: io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer
              dlqProducerProperties:
                configuration:
                  key.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
                  value.serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer
      default:
        binder: kafka
        producer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
        consumer:
          useNativeEncoding: true
      function:
        definition: myFunction
      bindings:
        my-in-0:
          binder: kafka
          destination: my-in-topic
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: myGroup
        my-out-0:
          binder: kafka
          destination: my-out-topic
          content-type: application/*+avro
          group: myGroup
```

Answer (score 0):

Disable dlq settings in the binding and configure the listener container (with a `ListenerContainerCustomizer` bean) with a `SeekToCurrentErrorHandler` configured with a `DeadLetterPublishingRecoverer`.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#error-handlers

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#dead-letters

Comment: So the Kafka binder DLQ setting doesn't support ErrorHandlingDeserializer?

Comment: Deserialization occurs much lower in the stack; `ErrorHandlingDeserializer` causes such exceptions to go directly to the error handler - the binder is not involved at all so the dead letter publishing has to be done from the error handler - there is an open issue to make this more seamless https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka/issues/1031

Comment: Here is a short write up on this particular use case: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/blob/main/recipes/recipe-3-handling-deserialization-errors-dlq-kafka.adoc